# The ViewData item that has the key 'User.RoleID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

When I execute the following code, I get this error. I can't seem to fix it. Can anybody help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Model:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public Users User { get; set; }
        public List<ExamGroups> AllGroups { get; set; }
        public List<ExamGroups> UserGroups { get; set; }
        //public List<> SelectedExamGroups { get; set; }
        public int[] SelectedGroups { get; set; }

    }
```

View:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.RoleID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.RoleID, (SelectList)ViewBag.UserRoles, "Seçiniz")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.RoleID)
        </div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create() { 
    ViewBag.UserRoles = new SelectList(db.ListItem.Where(a => a.ListID == 2), "ListValue", "ListText");
    var q = new SelectList(new[]{ new { ID= "1", Name="Aktif"}, new { ID= "0", Name="Pasif"}, } ,"ID","Name",1);
    ViewBag.Status = q; 
    return View(InitilizeData());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel users)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string IDs = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < users.SelectedGroups.Count(); i++)
        {
            IDs += users.SelectedGroups[i].ToString() + "|";
        }
        db.CreateUser(users.User.RegistryNo, users.User.Name, users.User.Surname, users.User.Password, users.User.RoleID, users.User.IsActive, IDs, users.User.LastLoginDate);
    } 
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the piece of code where you fil `ViewBag.UserRoles`?

Comment: public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.UserRoles = new SelectList(db.ListItem.Where(a => a.ListID == 2), "ListValue", "ListText");

            var q = new SelectList(new[]{
                 new { ID= "1", Name="Aktif"},
                 new { ID= "0", Name="Pasif"},
                }
                ,"ID","Name",1);
            ViewBag.Status = q;
            
            return View(InitilizeData());
        }

Comment: Try to replace this `new SelectList(db.ListItem.Where(a => a.ListID == 2), "ListValue", "ListText");` with `db.ListItem.Where(a => a.ListID == 2).Select(a => new SelectListItem{ Text = a.ListText, Value = a.ListValue });`. However, what is `ListValue`? It should be an integer.

Comment: It's an integer but it gives an error again.

Comment: Try to add an int field to your `UserViewModel` as `public int Test { get; set; }`, and then change this `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.RoleID...` to this `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Test...`

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Very stange.... Could you post `InitilizeData()` code?

Comment: UserViewModel userVM = new UserViewModel();
            userVM.AllGroups = new List<ExamGroups>() {
                new ExamGroups {ID=1,Name="Exam 1" },
                new ExamGroups {ID=2,Name="Exam 2" }
            }; userVM.UserGroups = new List<ExamGroups>()
            {   userVM.AllGroups[4],
                userVM.AllGroups[1],
                userVM.AllGroups[2],
            };
            userVM.SelectedGroups = userVM.UserGroups.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();
            return userVM;

Comment: I think the problem stems from the fact that when we create a new user and post it, we don't send a list to the dropdown, we send a single value. Is there a way to handle it in @Html.DropDownListFor(...) ?

Comment: What do you mean? In `ViewBag.UserRoles` there is an IEnumerable, so we have a list in the dropdownlist. How can work `userVM.AllGroups[4]` if `userVM.AllGroups` contains only two values?

Comment: Sir, there are additional 3 exam groups but I didn't add them due to restrictions. new ExamGroups {ID=3,Name="Exam 3" },
                new ExamGroups {ID=4,Name="Exam 4" },
                new ExamGroups {ID=5,Name="Exam 5" }